# Django test fails with "No User matches the given query."

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I wrote Django app and now I'm trying to cover it with automated tests. For testing `get_queryset` function within my `ListView` I created a test user and his post, but my test fails with `"No User matches the given query`". When I execute `py manage.py runserver` everything is fine, no exceptions are raised and the page's displayed properly. I'm new to Django testing so I absolutely have no idea what's going on. Could you help me please?

This is my view from view.py

```
class UserPostListView(ListView):
"""Displaying a page with a certain user's posts"""
model = Post
template_name = 'blog/user_posts.html'
context_object_name = 'posts'
paginate_by = 5

def get_queryset(self):
    """Dynamic filtering to get posts by a chosen user"""
    queryset = super().get_queryset()
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
    return queryset.filter(author=user).order_by('-date_posted')
```

Test for that view:

```
class TestUserPostListView(TestCase):
"""Test UserPostListView"""

def setUp(self):
    """Creating a test user and his post to see if the certain
    user's page with posts is displayed properly"""

    self.factory = RequestFactory()
    
    self.user = User.objects.create_user(
        username='test_user',
        email='testuser@example.com',
        password='fhhewo87539275'
    )
    self.post = Post.objects.create(
        title='test_post',
        content='blabla',
        author=self.user
    )
    
def test_get_queryset(self):
    """Testing get_queryset function"""
    url = reverse('user-posts', kwargs={'username': self.user.username})
    request = self.factory.get(url)
    view = UserPostListView()
    view.setup(request)

    queryset = view.get_queryset()
    self.assertIn(self.post, queryset)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\473491\Documents\django\web_blog\env\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 76, in get_object_or_404
return queryset.get(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\473491\Documents\django\web_blog\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 435, in get
raise self.model.DoesNotExist(django.contrib.auth.models.User.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\473491\Documents\django\web_blog\web_blog\apps\blog\test\test_views.py", line 67, in test_get_queryset
queryset = view.get_queryset()
File "C:\Users\473491\Documents\django\web_blog\web_blog\apps\blog\views.py", line 45, in get_queryset
user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
File "C:\Users\473491\Documents\django\web_blog\env\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 78, in get_object_or_404
raise Http404('No %s matches the given query.' % queryset.model._meta.object_name)
```

django.http.response.Http404: No User matches the given query.

Comment: Is `self.kwargs.get('username')` returning None? What happens when you print User.objects.all() at the view?

Comment: It doesn't. When I print User.objects.all() I get <QuerySet [<User: Admin>, <User: TestUser>, <User: new_test_user>]> because I created some users to test my app manually. While running test empty instance of DB is created.

Comment: This can be a bit useless but try as the example does
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/advanced/#example

`UserPostListView.as_view()(request)`

Comment: I've already read the docs and I wrote my tests in accordance with it. I realized I have a problem in `queryset = view.get_queryset()` but I don't understand what's going

Comment: Maybe start by printing self.kwargs.get('username') and see if it returns the actual user you're expecting

Answer (score 1):

I have found out where the problem was. My `UserPostListView` is called by the url containing url-variable.

My urlpattern corresponding to the view:

```
path('users/<str:username>', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-posts')
```

I also use `username` from the url to filter out posts created by the user with that username by calling `get_queryset` function in `UserPostListView`.

I read the docs attentively and found:

> When the view is called during the request/response cycle, the setup() method assigns the HttpRequest to the view’s request attribute, and any positional and/or keyword arguments captured from the URL pattern to the args and kwargs attributes, respectively.

It means that instead of `view.setup(request)` I had to write `view.setup(request, username=self.user.username)`

When I fixed it the test started running properly and didn't fail.